# Why SUM(PMT) is not identical to FV?

Tags: loans, calculation, compound-interest

I'm exploring financial functions in a spreadsheet. When I use FV, which is [based on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_value#Compound_interest) `FV = PV*(1+r)^n` I get a different number than when using PMT and multiplying by the number of periods.

For example:

- Principal: $250,000.00
- Interest rate: 2.50%
- Interest rate per period: 0.21% (`2.50%/12`)
- Amortization: 25
- Num of periods (months): 300 (`25*12`)
- Monthly payment: $1,121.54 (`PMT(2.5%/12,25*12,-$250,000)`)
- Sum of all monthly pmts: **$336,462.55** (`300*$1,121.54`)
- FV function: **$466,757.93** (`FV(2.5%/12,25*12,0,-$250,000)`)
- However, `FV(2.5%/12,25*12,$1121.54,-$250,000)` return $0.

In other words, how come FV with "0" monthly payments evaluates at $466k, but FV with $1121 monthly payment (which sums up to $336k and not $466k) evaluate at 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing two different scenarios.

**`FV(2.5%/12,25*12,$1121.54,-$250,000)`**

This says, I borrowed $250,000 and I want to know how much I will own if I pay off  $1121.54 each month for 25 years and the interest rate is 2.5%.

That means you're gradually reducing your principal, so the interest accruing each month gradually reduces.

**`PMT(2.5%/12,25*12,-$250,000)*300`**

This is the total amount you would pay if you paid $1121.54 each month.

**`FV(2.5%/12,25*12,0,-$250,000)`**

This says, I borrowed $250,000 and I want to know how much I will own if I don't pay anything for 25 years and the interest rate is 2.5%.

That means the amount you owe continues to grow, so the extra interest each month will be larger.

This is conceptually similar to a scenario in which you invest a sum of money ($250,000) in a 2.5% portfolio, but withdraw $1121 on a monthly basis: you would end up with much more if you didn't withdraw at all and waited instead.

---

The difference between the two scenarios is why, if you take out a mortgage, you should always pay your monthly amount!  And why, if you don't, the bank will come after you and foreclose!